# unable to read a text file after returning the file from a dfferent function

Tags: python, file

I have a code where i am writing somelines to a file and then trying to read the file in a separate function.

```
def start():
    task_file, task_dir, command_file=parse_json_and_create_folders()
    for i in range(len(task_file)):
        with open('sscd_file', 'a') as mfile:
            dir_name = "TASKFOLDER" + str(i)
            file_path= task_dir + "/" + dir_name
            os.chdir(file_path)
            inp_file=command_file.rsplit('/', 1)[-1]
            wor_folder=command_file.rsplit('/', 1)[-2]
            inp_file_path=os.path.join(file_path, wor_folder)
            line = "-E " + "cd" + file_path + " -o " + file_path + "-%T.out" + application_name + " inp=" + inp_file
            mfile.write(line)
    return mfile.name

def read_task_file():
    myfile=start()
    with open(myfile, 'r') as f:
        print(f.readlines())
```

read_task_file()

When i am trying to read this file in my read() , the error says

```
    with open(myfile, 'r') as f:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'sscd_file'
```

I am not sure what is wrong here.
can someone help me here

Comment: Could you share also `parse_json_and_create_folders()`? and why is there an `os.chdir()` in the middle of your with statement?

Answer (score 1):

You changed directory with `os.chdir(file_path)` and didn't go back to the original directory. Now Python will search for the file in the new current directory, `file_path`.

As stated [in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#open), `open` works with paths that are "absolute or *relative to the current working directory*". A path like `"the_file"` is a relative path, so `open` will indeed search for this file in the new current directory.

Here's an example:

```
>>> os.listdir() # the contents of the current directory
['.DS_Store', 'fof.pyc', 'test_venv', 'fof.py', '__pycache__', 'test.py', 'compile_ios', 'venv', 'v']
>>> with open('hello.txt', 'w') as f: # open a file in THIS directory
...  os.chdir('venv') # change to another directory
...  f.write('hello!')
... 
6
>>> os.getcwd() # I remain in this new directory 
'/Users/forcebru/test/venv'
>>> os.listdir() # there's no 'hello.txt'
['bin', 'include', 'pyvenv.cfg', 'lib']
>>> os.chdir('..') # go back
>>> os.getcwd()
'/Users/forcebru/test'
>>> os.listdir() # 'hello.txt' is here, as expected
['.DS_Store', 'fof.pyc', 'test_venv', 'fof.py', '__pycache__', 'test.py', 'compile_ios', 'venv', 'hello.txt', 'v']
>>>
```

Opening using the absolute path with `open("/Users/forcebru/test/hello.txt")` will open this exact file, irregardless of the current working directory.

Comment: yeah, thats my bad, i gave the full path and it works. But when i open the file for reading it gives me the data in list format is that expected,

Comment: @prex, what command are you using and what's its output? `read()`, for example, will always return a single string, but `readlines()` will return a list of strings.